# android: Layout not getting displayed properly

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I have an application which supports all android devices i.e it have a default, small, normal, Large layout

It is working fine on all devices except LG L5 E610, I believe it picks a layout file from normal layout. I don't know what's wrong with it. Any suggestions?

Comment: PLS .Post your layouts

Comment: Also, post the names of your layout folders, may be a problem with a qualifier.